# Get touch events in a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitextview, touch-event

Apple does not provide touch event handling for `UITextView`. The project I'm developing includes notes that can be readable and editable, and I am using a `UITextView`. Please help me with this problem -- how can I get touch events for my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using my own logic.

While reading we are adding a `Custom View` over the `textview` and working with those methods:

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But when we are in the editing mode it is not possible anymore. Anyhow my requirement is only in readable mode.

Thanks for all your support to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Apple documentation, you may set a delegate for UITextView and implement the UITextViewDelegate.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

Specifically, you can determine that a UITextView was touched by implementing **textViewShouldBeginEditing**.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

Be sure to set the delegate property on the UITextView in order to catch the event.

Comment: thanks for response

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
these method will call only when [textView seteditable:yes]; but if i want to change color of some text background  i must  disable the editing.
 and please let me know how to insert image at certain place in 
ui-textview. please if possible post some reliable code here

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not need to disable the editing in order to change the background!

Also, you could always wrap the UITextView in a custom UIView, and catch touch events on that (using a delegate as necessary). I do this to catch touch events on MKMapView with ease. This is a great approach, and will not compromise your UITextViewDelegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to Kevin's answer. UITextView inherits from UIScrollView. You should be getting all the events declared in UIScrollViewDelegate protocol for the text view.

I got:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

when I declared my class as the delegate of UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom textview and provide touch events inside the custom class. then you can create methods in delegate of that custom class.