# How can we detect touch up or click events in textview in IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In IPhone?

Do we need a button control instead for that?

How can we pull that one up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get touch event for uitextview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108224/how-to-get-touch-event-for-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle touch events directly in your view controller but this is usually a lot of effort. If you use a button with the type as custom it will look the same as a textview.

Answer (score 0):

subclass UITextView and implement - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}

Comment: And how the hell xcode knows that the function should handle touchesBegan?

Comment: That is why I asked you to subclass the UITextView